# RGB to grayscale

Tags: opencv

I am trying to convert RGB to grayscale. But the output is same as the original video. please let me know the error in this code. It would be very helpful.

```
IplImage *myimage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(videoFrame),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
cvZero(myimage);
CvScalar pixelvalue, setpixelvalue; 
        for (int i=0;i<videoFrame->height;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<videoFrame->width;j++)
            {
                pixelvalue = cvGet2D(videoFrame, i, j); 

                 int b= pixelvalue.val[0];
                 int g= pixelvalue.val[1];
                 int r= pixelvalue.val[2];


                     int gc= r*0.299+g*0.587+b*0.114;
                 setpixelvalue.val[0]=gc; 

                cvSet2D(myimage, i, j, setpixelvalue);
                        cvSet2D(myimage, i, j, pixelvalue);


                }

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the calculated value:

```
cvSet2D(myimage, i, j, setpixelvalue); //here you are setting pixel value at setpixelvalue
cvSet2D(myimage, i, j, pixelvalue); //and here you overwrite it - change to pixelvalue
```

Remove second this line `cvSet2D(myimage, i, j, pixelvalue);` from you code. Also I think that there is no need to you 3 channels, 1 will be enough - change first line of your code to `IplImage *myimage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(videoFrame),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);`. If for some reason you want you image to have 3 channels than you have to set all 3 channels to calculated value - leave first line of you code unmodified and change this part:

```
int gc= r*0.299+g*0.587+b*0.114;
setpixelvalue.val[0]=gc;
```

to this:

```
int gc= r*0.299+g*0.587+b*0.114;
setpixelvalue.val[0]=gc; 
setpixelvalue.val[1]=gc; 
setpixelvalue.val[2]=gc;
```

Of course in OpenCV there is a function for converting image from one color space to another - http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-cvtcolor

Comment: @Kaka I would also add: use cv::Mat instead of the old IplImage